# How to Find All Resource IDs in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, resources

I know how to find a resource given a certain id (e.g. `getResources().getString(R.string.myString`), but if I want to get a list of all the id names, how do I do that?

Comment: Generally, that is not a good idea, as there will be *many* more resources of common types in your app, coming from various libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare generally you are right, but consider my case. I got a special naming conversion for resources, and for QA proposes, I need to list all the app resources.

Comment: @IlyaGazman: Then reflection is your only runtime option, as shown in the answer. Or, investigate creating some compile-time option that code-generates the relevant list of IDs.

Answer (score 4):

it is `R.resource.class.getFields()`

for instance

```
Field[] fields = R.id.class.getFields();
for(int z = 0; z < fields.length; z++){
    someArray[z] = fields[z].getInt();
}
```

Comment: Works better than I expected, I had to do....  fields[z].getInt(fields[z])